# Visible deprecation warning using boolean operation on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations

I'm having an issue where I keep receiving  a warning stating:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; 
dimension is 744 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

When I try to use this:

```
x_low = xcontacts[(xcontacts[5:6] <= 2000).any(1), :]
x_med = xcontacts[(xcontacts[5:6] <= 4000).any(1), :]
x_med = xcontacts[(xcontacts[5:6] > 2000).any(1), :]
x_hi  = xcontacts[(xcontacts[5:6] > 4000).any(1), :]
```

On an array of shape:

```
xcontacts.shape
Out[46]: (744L, 6L)
```

Here's a sample of the array:

```
[[   1.        0.        0.        4.        0.      228.681 ]
 [   2.        4.        0.        8.        0.      219.145 ]
 [   3.        8.        0.       12.        0.      450.269 ]
 ..., 
 [  60.      236.       96.      240.       96.      933.4565]
 [  61.      240.       96.      244.       96.      646.449 ]
 [  62.      244.       96.      248.       96.      533.657 ]]
```

I'm trying to create three new arrays which are copies of the first but after a boolean operation has been performed on the final column, removing rows that do not agree with the operator:

```
x_low where col5 <= 2000
x_med where 2000 < col5 <= 4000
x_hi where 4000 < col5
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should be `xcontacts[:, 5:6] <= 2000` or just `xcontacts[:, 5] <= 2000`. Note `xcontacts[5:6]` means 5th row instead of 5th col. That's why the shape does not match and causes warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Syrtis Major for this:

```
x_low = xcontacts[(xcontacts[:,5] <= 2000)]
x_med = xcontacts[(xcontacts[:,5] <= 4000)]
x_med = xcontacts[(xcontacts[:,5] > 2000)]
x_hi  = xcontacts[(xcontacts[:,5] > 4000)]
```